# Android Google Maps V2 Unhand led Exception

Tags: android, google-maps

I am New for andorid developing.. I followed the tutorial in google maps for android.

[image][image][image]

And I added google play services library.

My manifest file with permissions

[Mainfest File](http://www.codeshare.io/bbCb0)

My main activity:

[Main Activity](http://www.codeshare.io/qO1KJ)

My Layout Flie:

[layout file](http://www.codeshare.io/4ssXy)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've just read the error message it would have been clear.

You need the version meta tag in your manifest file:

```
<application ... >
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Can you tell me whats changes I have to do in order to make it work for >API11

Comment: @user3616287 you need `android:minSdkVersion="11"` for that.

Comment: but i want develope an app for both API<11 and API>11

Comment: HOw to get Google Play services in emmulator

Comment: @user3616287 Google it and stop deriving multiple questions from this one. If it has been answered select the answer and ask another one.